# Display a specific item inside a list through json

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display a list table of employee along with welfares for each. My api return specific details of a welfare and I want to display welfareTitle.

I have try two ways:

```
<div *ngFor="let elements of key.welfareEW">
          {{elements.welfare[2]}}
</div>
```

This return nothing

```
<div *ngFor="let elements of key.welfareEW">
          <div *ngFor="let welfareName of welfareEW.welfare">
            {{welfareName.welfareTitle}}
          </div>        
</div>
```

And this return with the error "Cannot read property 'welfare' of undefined"

My Json

```
[
    {
        "welfareEW": [
            {
                "welfare": {
                    "employeeWF": [],
                    "welfareID": 1,
                    "welfareTitle": "Corn"
                },
                "employeeID": 1,
                "welfareID": 1
            },
            {
                "welfare": {
                    "employeeWF": [],
                    "welfareID": 2,
                    "welfareTitle": "Shit"
                },
                "employeeID": 1,
                "welfareID": 2
            }
        ],
        "employeeID": 1,
        "employeeName": "Binh Phuoi"
    },
    {
        "welfareEW": [],
        "employeeID": 2,
        "employeeName": "cxcssdsd"
    },
    {
        "welfareEW": [
            {
                "welfare": {
                    "employeeWF": [],
                    "welfareID": 3,
                    "welfareTitle": "Lon"
                },
                "employeeID": 3,
                "welfareID": 3
            }
        ],
        "employeeID": 3,
        "employeeName": "So 3"
    }
]
```

Comment: can you share a stackBlitz showing what you have currently achieved then may be some one can better help you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
<div *ngFor="let elements of key">
  <div *ngFor="let element of elements.welfareEW">
        {{element.welfare.welfareTitle}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq5ocw

As per my understanding you are looping in wrong way. Best way to do is just print data in each loop

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <div *ngFor="let it of item.welfareEW">
      {{ it.employeeID }}
      {{ it.welfareID }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

it is not very clear what you are asking for. May be this will help

Comment: No, I don't wanna display employeeID or welfareID. Also I have managed to display it just by 'elements.welfareID' or 'elements.employeeID' in my first way of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to avoid unnecessary hierarchy in your JSON, if you can minimize you should, that way you don't have to include too many null reference checks in your code,

for example in below code ideally you should have checks in place in order to ensure that `welfareInfo` which actually is `emp.welfareEW` and `welfareInfo.welfare` exists before trying to access `welfareInfo.welfare.welfareTitle`.

any way you should try some thing like this,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let emp of employeeList">

    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let welfareInfo of emp.welfareEW">
        Employee: {{emp.employeeName}},
        WelfareTitle: {{welfareInfo.welfare.welfareTitle}}
    </mat-list-item>

</ng-container>
```

output:

[image]

and here is a link to the working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8puxri?embed=1&file=src/app/list-overview-example.html),